# Swift 3 Generic Extension Arguments

Tags: swift, generics, dictionary, swift3, swift-extensions

In Swift 2.x, I had a nice little setup that allowed me to store and retrieve dictionary values using enum members:

```
public enum UserDefaultsKey : String {
    case mainWindowFrame
    case selectedTabIndex
    case recentSearches
}

extension Dictionary where Key : String {
    public subscript(key: UserDefaultsKey) -> Value? {
        get { return self[key.rawValue] }
        set { self[key.rawValue] = newValue }
    }
}
```

This allowed me to access values like this:

```
let dict = userDefaults.dictionaryForKey("SearchPrefs")
if let recentSearches = dict?[.recentSearches] as? [String] {
    // Populate "Recent" menu items
}
```

… instead of having to access values like this:

```
let dict = userDefaults.dictionaryForKey("SearchPrefs")
if let recentSearches = dict?[UserDefaultsKey.recentSearches.rawValue] as? [String] {
    // Populate "Recent" menu items
}
```

***Note:** The use of a string literal to access the dictionary from `NSUserDefaults` is for example purposes only. I wouldn't actually go out of my way to use an enum for dictionary keys, only to use a string literal to access the dictionary itself. :-)*

---

Anyway, this has worked great for my needs, and it made reading and maintaining code involving `NSUserDefaults` a lot more pleasant.

Since migrating my project to Swift 3, however, I'm getting the following error:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: String {
    public subscript(key: UserDefaultsKey) -> Value? { <---- Use of undeclared type 'Value'
                                              ~~~~~~
        get {
            return self[key.rawValue]
        }
        set {
            self[key.rawValue] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

I looked at the generated headers for `Dictionary`, and the generic `Key` and `Value` arguments are still present in the [Generic Argument Clause](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GenericParametersAndArguments.html) of the `Dictionary` struct, so I'm not too sure what the issue is.

Do I need to rewrite the `where` clause to conform to some new Swift 3 grammar I'm unaware of? Or … can one no longer access generic placeholder types in extensions?

I just don't know what to do!

My project has only 28 migration errors left to resolve. I'm so close to actually getting to use Swift 3, so I'd love any pointers (as long as they're not `Unsafe` and/or `Raw`).

Thanks!

Comment: That shouldn't have worked in Swift 2 either... A generic parameter of a concrete type cannot be constrained to be a concrete type, unfortunately.

Comment: @TimVermeulen Although I agree with you, I've resorted to this "hackery" in multiple places, and it still seems to work in other extensions (don't quote me). How might one go about rewriting it to have it work, while remaining "generic?" I remember trying all sorts of fun things like having `String` conform to some empty `StringLike` protocol, and using that as the generic constraint, but it ended up not working for one reason or another. I guess my problem comes down to "properly" implementing protocol-oriented design patterns.

Comment: Related (and possible duplicate?): [Subscript: access my dictionary values with a String enumeration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499137/subscript-access-my-dictionary-values-with-a-string-enumeration)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A generic parameter of a concrete type cannot be constrained to a concrete type, currently. This means that something like

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String
```

won't compile. It's a limitation of the generics system, and it hopefully won't be a problem in Swift 4.

There is a workaround though, but it's a bit hacky:

```
protocol StringConvertible {
    init(_ string: String)
}

extension String: StringConvertible {}

extension Dictionary where Key: StringConvertible {

    subscript(key: UserDefaultsKey) -> Value? {
        get { return self[Key(key.rawValue)] }
        set { self[Key(key.rawValue)] = newValue }
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, haha, I guess great minds think alike. This is what I came up with right before you posted: {{ Almost exactly the same code omitted due to formatting constraints. }} And … so far, so good. I'll give you the checkmark! Thanks, Tim!

Comment: `as! Key` won't invoke the initialiser, though, so that doesn't work :)

Comment: Touché. It worked in my Playground, but I'll implement your suggestion to be safe. Again, thanks for helping on this. Only 27 errors left!

Comment: The workaround now seems to give error `<unknown>:0: error: non-failable initializer requirement 'init' cannot be satisfied by a failable initializer ('init?')`

Comment: Concrete same-type requirements are now supported in Swift 3.1, available with Xcode 8.3 beta :)